# cannot bootup after upgrading the system `Arch linux`, should I format my machine?

Tags: archlinux

So here is what I did before becoming unable to bootup, I used `sudo pacman -Syu` to upgrade the system, then tabs in all browsers start to crash due to the library `glibc`, so I tried to downgrade it using a package I installed using `yay -S downgrade`, finally I restart my machine and I get this screen:[image]

what I should do?

Comment: You probably still can get into the system through the installation CD. From in-there, you can basically try to repair. There is no direct need to completely reinstall the system.

Comment: thank you, but actually i am sick of arch moving to ubuntu

Comment: Arch is not necessarily for everybody. If you are not ready to _(constantly)_ repair or break your own system, it is probably not for you.

Comment: @funilrys 11 years of Arch experience, 4 update-induced boot failures. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @hidefromkgb I feel your pain ;-) 10 years of Arch experience, and a lot more of boot failures. Am I doing something right? It's mainly because in my free time besides OSS coding, I like to experiment and discover ways of breaking my machine! I'm not getting away. It's a joy!